# How to get all clickable elements on the webpage using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

For webscraping purpose, I want to find all URLs present on the website which I can access using the tag 'a'. Refer to the below script

```
   // Get all urls in the page
        let urls = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let results = [];
            let items = document.querySelectorAll('a');
            items.forEach((item) => {
                results.push({
                    url: item.href,
                });

            });
```

Now there are some URLs hidden, and which can be accessed using clicking on the elements on the page. How can get the list of all clickable elements on a page using puppeteer or nodejs?

Comment: In other words, there are elements which are not `<a>` tags but which have event listeners that respond to `click` events and you want to find those elements? Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-when-debugging-or-from-the-javascript